# Why do we say 'our sister______'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Why do we refer to something related as

> our sister_______?

For example:

> Please visit our sister hotel
>
> You can find that on our sister site

Why don't we use brother? Is it wrong to use brother?

Comment: Related: [When and why do you call it a sister-site?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139654/when-and-why-do-you-call-it-a-sister-site) and [Usage and origin of “sister” in expressions like “sister company, sister ship, sister site” etc](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/369932/usage-and-origin-of-sister-in-expressions-like-sister-company-sister-ship-s)

Comment: Also: [Why use the term “Sister sites” instead of “Brother sites”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41425/why-use-the-term-sister-sites-instead-of-brother-sites)

Comment: None of the answers in the duplicate questions are especially satisfying.